# Scala - Gatling - JsonPath - Check if object with specific value exist

Tags: scala, gatling, jsonpath

I have a jsonpath respone like:

```
{
  "pageable": {
    "currentPage": 1,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "pageSize": 20,
    "last": true,
    "first": true
  },
  "sort": {
    "orders": [],
    "sorted": false,
    "unsorted": true,
    "empty": true
  },
  "totalElements": 6,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "roleName": "test1",
      "userCount": 5
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "roleName": "test2",
      "userCount": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to check that the data with id == 1 exist.
I tried some combinations like:

```
checks ::= jsonPath("$..data.*[?(@.id=='1')]").exists
checks ::= jsonPath("$.data.*[?(@.id=='1')]").exists
checks ::= jsonPath("$..data[?(@.id=='1')]..id").exists
checks ::= jsonPath("$..data[?(@.id=='1')].id").exists
checks ::= jsonPath("$.data[?(@.id=='1')].id").exists
```

But no path works, I'm getting error:

```
jsonPath($..data..*[?(@.id=='1')]).find.exists, found nothing
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to use JsonPath [whose syntax is unclear and lacks a standard](https://gatling.io/2019/07/introducing-jmespath-support/), you should try [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/) instead, that [Gatling supports as well](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/check/#jsonpath).

```scala
jmesPath("data[?id == `1`]")
```